# Azure App Service Plan CPU spikes for no obvious reason

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We're experiencing CPU spikes on our Azure App Service Plan for no obvious reason. Its not something that stops the service, but we'd like to have an understanding of when&how that kind of things happen.

For example, CPU percentage sits at 0-1% range for days but then all of the sudden it spikes to 98%, 45%, 60% and comes back to 0-1% range very quickly. Memory stays unchanged at comfortable 40-45% level, no incoming requests to it, no web jobs, nothing unusual in logs, no failures, service health ok, nothing we could point our finger to as a reason.
We tried to find out through kudu > support > analyze (metrics)...but we couldn't get request submited. It just keeps giving error to try later.

There is only one web app running in that app service plan, its a asp.net core 2.0. web api.

Could someone shed some light on this kind of behavior? Is this normal, expected? If so, why it happens? Is there a danger that it spikes to 90% and don't immediately come back?

Just, what's going on?

Comment: I can only answer part of this question: it is NOT normal. I haven't seen random unexplained CPU spikes like that on my Web App instances. What's your pricing tier and instance size? Do you by chance have any site extensions running? There's no PHP apps running around like a WordPress blog? How long does this spike last?

Comment: Pricing tier is Basic, instance size is B1, the first one in Basic tier. No site extensions running, no blogs, phps, anything like that. Just a single asp.net core rest web api running in it.Its hard to tell how long spike lasts because chart doesnt show below 1 minute granularity but its below one minute.

Comment: Have you looked through all of the metrics under Diagnose and Solve Problems -> Metrics per instance -> Perf Counters to see if there's something else correlated such as a spike in threads, IO Read Operations/sec, etc? I've found clues to what's going on by just looking through everything.

Comment: I thought i did 5 times, i have spent 3 hours looking through all i could think of. Will do one more time to triple check and come back here with results.

Comment: @RobReagan nope, everything flat there. Now, what might be the problem in spotting things like that is that it lasts very short, i could see it only in Metrics in 'last hour' chart as soon as it gets to some wider timeframe charts, it gets averaged out and because of very short time it spikes, you just can't notice it on bigger timeframes. Do you know if there is maybe some conditional process dump/snapshot that would trigger if CPU goes above some %?

Comment: @RobReagan I've just got another 60% spike, as reported by Metrics CPU Percentage chart for App Service Plan. No requests, no nothing. Interesting thing is that in Diagnose And Solve Problems > Metrics per instance...the chart for Service Plan reports CPU spike but CPU for actual Web app running within the App service Plan (the only one) sits at 0. So this makes me think its something else than my web app itself. But what - that's complete mistery for me.

Comment: I cannot think of a reason that could occur so frequently given the lack of traffic and spikes in other perf counters. There's behind-the-scenes processes that take place (patching the underlying OS, crash recovery, etc), but that wouldn't explain your frequent issues. I'll keep my thinking cap on in regards to this issue.

Comment: @RobReagan I've issued support request about it and we'll see what they say. I'll come back with results here.

Comment: My only other suggestion (which may be drastic depending on the complexity of your solution) is to re-provision a totally new instance and see if these problems persist.

Comment: @RobReagan yes, that is one option i also had on mind, definitely. Holidays & weekend are a lucky circumstance now as there will be no traffic but i'd still like to get some understanding behind it. Will keep post here about findings.

Comment: @RobReagan Here is the response from MSN support: **"We reviewed our internal tools taking as starting point 12/26 and today 12/29 and we could notice that this was majority System processes doing background tasks, which is normal for each sandbox environment. In your case, it was mostly MonAgentCore.exe fluctuating in CPU which is our diagnostic log capturing process and this looks like a very temporary spike and appears normal."** / So, seems to be normal thing on App Service platform and a part of their monitor tools.

Comment: I would post this as the answer and accept it in case anyone else experiences this issue and stumbles across this thread. Nice work, by the way.

Comment: @RobReagan thank you, sir. Just posted as answer so someone else can make use of it if needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After speaking with MS support i've got an answer it is a normal behavior coming from their monitoring tool:

> We reviewed our internal tools taking as starting point 12/26 and
>   today 12/29 and we could notice that this was majority System
>   processes doing background tasks, which is normal for each sandbox
>   environment. In your case, it was mostly MonAgentCore.exe fluctuating
>   in CPU which is our diagnostic log capturing process and this looks
>   like a very temporary spike and appears normal.

Comment: I get this when I create a brand new App service plan even with 0 apps in it. So the answer it ignore the 100% spikes?

Comment: @DanParker for my case, yes, the answer was its normal. I'm not sure if the answer is the same for your app service plan with no apps in it. Maybe better for you to send a support request and confirm it for your particular case.