# Web App Service - How often should it be restarted?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I deployed an Azure web app back in July and it's been running flawlessly up until about three weeks ago. At that time, I would notice my CPU utilization constantly between 80% to 100%, with no corresponding increase in traffic. The first time I saw this, after concluding it wasn't my app, or increased traffic, causing this, I restarted the web app service and the CPU utilization returned to its normal 5% to 15%. Then after a couple days it started to do it again. And, again, a restart solved the issue.

My question is this. Is this normal to have to restart the web service every day or so? And, if so, why?

Comment: Adding to Rob's suggestions. Yes. you should not be restarting the WebApp to fix the issue rather get insight into what's triggering increased CPU consumption. First, create a process dump, and then analyze the process dump. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2016/01/20/how-to-capture-dump-when-intermittent-high-cpu-happens-on-azure-web-app/ 

It is a good idea to check the Azure Service Health for any issues: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-health/service-health-overview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming no changes have been made to your code and you have not seen a corresponding increase in traffic, it is not normal. An Azure Web App with no app deployed should almost always stay at 0% CPU utilization. I say "almost always" because Microsoft does run diagnostic and monitoring tools in the background that can cause some very temporary spikes. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48012689/azure-app-service-plan-cpu-spikes-for-no-obvious-reason#comment83023209_48012689) for a thread on that particular issue.

My recommendations are:

1. When CPU pegs and stays pegged, log into your SCM site. Check the Process Explorer and confirm that it's your w3wp.exe (Note there's a separate w3wp.exe for your SCM site.) that's pegged the CPU.
2. Ensure that you don't have any Site Extensions or WebJobs that are losing their mind. You can check your installed Site Extensions on the SCM site under the Site Extensions -> Installed tab. Any WebJobs will show up on your SCM process explorer as separate processes from step #1.
3. Log into the Azure Portal and browse to your Web App's management blade. Go to the Diagnose and Solve Problems blade. From here, you can try "Metrics per Instance" and go through all of the Perf Counters to see if it gives you a clue as to what's wrong. For example, I had SignalR go nuts once and only found it by seeing that my thread count was out of control.
4. On the Diagnose and Solve Problems blade, you can also check Application Events.
5. You may have some light shed on this by installing Application Insights on your web application. It has a free tier that will likely have enough space to troubleshoot for a few days. If this is something going bananas with your code, you may get some insight here.
6. I'm including failed request tracing logs here for completeness. But these would likely show up in Application Insights.
7. If you've exhausted all of these possibilities, file a support ticket with Microsoft. As the above link shows, they have access to diagnostic tools that we don't and can eliminate the possibility of a runaway diagnostics or infrastructure process. I don't know how much help they can be if the CPU spike is due to your own w3wp.exe that's spiking the CPU.

Of course, if your app is seriously easy to redeploy and it's not a ridiculous hassle, you can just re-provision it and see if you see the same behavior.

Comment: @RandyMinder, did you have any luck resolving the issue?

Comment: No because the problem hasn't occurred again since the last time I restarted the app service.